# Create configmap with outside yaml files for kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm quite new for kubernetes. I am trying to create configmap with using yaml file which was user defined.

```
helm upgrade --install test --namespace test --create-namespace . -f xxx/user-defined.yaml
```

user can add any yaml file with using 'f' option.
for example;

```
cars.yaml
cars:
  - name: Mercedes
    model: E350
```

So command will be;

```
helm upgrade --install test --namespace test --create-namespace . -f xxx/cars.yaml
```

My question is, I want to create configmap which is name 'mercedes-configmap'
I need to read that values from cars.yaml and create automaticaly configmap with name and data of cars.yaml

Update,
I've created below configmap template;

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.cars.name }}-configmap
data:
  {{- range .Files }}
    {{ .Files.Get . | toYaml | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

The only issue that I faced, I couldnt get the whole file data.

Comment: Is my understanding correct that users can submit different structures and filenames or is there any structure?

Comment: user can add like cars.yaml which is mentioned question body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the community!

I have created a helm template for `configmap`. It works this way: you can pass configmap name - `name` and file name - `fname` where data is stored and/or it can read files from a specific folder.

Please find the template (first 3 lines are commented, it's two working implementations of logic to check values existing):

```
{{/*
{{ if not (or (empty .Values.name) (empty .Values.fname)) }}
*/}}

{{ if and (not (empty .Values.name)) (not (empty .Values.fname)) }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}-configmap
data:
  {{- ( .Files.Glob .Values.fname ).AsConfig | nindent 2 }}
---
{{ end }}
{{ $currentScope := .}}
{{ range $path, $_ :=  .Files.Glob  "userfiles/*.yaml" }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ base $path | trimSuffix ".yaml" }}-configmap
data:
  {{- with $currentScope}}
  {{ base $path }}: |
    {{- ( .Files.Get $path ) | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
---
{{ end }}
```

First part of the `template` checks if configmap name and file name are set and if so, it renders it. Second part goes to `userfiles` directory and gets all `yamls` within.

You find [github repo](https://github.com/fivecatscats/helm-create-configmap) where I shared file examples and configmap.

To render the template with `cars2.yaml` and with/without files within `userfiles` directory:

```
helm template . --set name=cars2 --set fname=cars2.yaml
```

To render the same template with only files in `userfiles` directory:

```
helm template .
```

P.S. helm v3.5.4 was used

---

Useful links:

- [Accessing files in helm](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/)
- [Flow control](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/)
- [File path functions](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#file-path-functions)

Comment: Yes Wytrzymały Wiktor :)  Thanks to @moonkotte